# Waiting for file to upload before sending to S3?

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3, laravel, laravel-3, appfog

Im having a problem with larger files using Laravel on Appfog, uploading to Amazon S3.

It works perfectly fine, for files between 1kb and 1.5Mb.
But any larger, and it fails.

It appears the reason for this, is the server is obviously firing the S3 upload code, before the file is actually uploaded and in memory on the server.

Because the error message is an unhandled exception returned by the S3 Laravel Bundle...

Saying....

```
   S3::inputFile(): Unable to open input file:
```

When I upload/run this function locally via wamp with the same file it works just fine.  And makes it to S3 perfectly.

Its only when the file is going over the wire through to my appfog app, that it breaks.  Because the upload locally takes 20ms, and the upload over the wire takes about 4 seconds.

This shows me that its obviously firing the code before the file has arrived or something along those lines.

And again, it works through my app perfectly fine, when the files are smallish.  Only when theyre a bit larger it breaks.

Any ideas???

```
public function action_uploadfile(){
    $input = Input::all();

    if(!empty($input['theDoc']['name'])){

        $file = Input::file('theDoc');
        $s = Setting::shortcode();
        $id = $input['theID']."-".$input['leadID'];
        $path_parts = pathinfo($file['name']);
        $ext = $path_parts['extension'];

            if(!empty($input['theName'])){
                $filename = $input['theName'].".".$ext;
            } else {
                $filename = $file['name'];
            }

            if((!empty($file))&&(S3::inputFile($file['tmp_name'], false))){

                if(S3::putObject($input2, 'myAMAZONBucket', $s."/".$id."/".$filename, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)){
                $file2 = Doc::where('uri','=', $s."/".$id."/".$filename)->get();
                if($file2){
                  // duplicate file/document error goes here
                } else {
                    $f = New Doc;
                    $f->lead_id = $input['leadID'];
                    $f->sale_id = $input['theID'];
                    $f->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
                    $f->notes = $input['theNotes'];
                    $f->filetype = $ext;
                    $f->filesize = $file['size'];
                    $f->filename = $filename;
                    $f->uri = $s."/".$id."/".$filename;
                    if($f->save()){
                     return Redirect::back();
                    };
                }
            } else {
                 //Cannot read file error
            }

            } else {
                 //Failed upload error
            }

        } else {
           //No file selected error
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using some ini_set()'s to play with things like max_execution_time and set_time_limit to see if one of those is set too low.

Comment: Its interesting that you say that....because my max_execution_time on my local machine is 30 seconds, and on the server thats having the problem, its 300 seconds......I dont get it???